# group by in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following DataFrame:

```
     email   cat  class_price
0   email1@gmail.com  cat1            1
1   email2@gmail.com  cat2            2
2   email3@gmail.com  cat2            4
3   email1@gmail.com  cat2            4
4   email2@gmail.com  cat2            1
5   email3@gmail.com  cat1            3
6   email1@gmail.com  cat1            2
7   email2@gmail.com  cat2            1
8   email3@gmail.com  cat2            4
9   email1@gmail.com  cat2            2
10  email2@gmail.com  cat3            1
11  email3@gmail.com  cat1            1
```

And I want to group by email and by class_price, for each line I want to take the max of class_price.

I'm using:

```
test_df2 = test_df.groupby(['email','cat'])['class_price'].max()
```

The output is:

```
email             cat 
email1@gmail.com  cat1    2
                  cat2    4
email2@gmail.com  cat2    2
                  cat3    1
email3@gmail.com  cat1    3
                  cat2    4
```

But how can I get a result similar to a sql group by? ie:

```
email             cat1   cat2   cat3  
email1@gmail.com    2     4      0
email2@gmail.com    0     2      1
email3@gmail.com    3     4      0
```

Comment: [It's not super-important, but your example output isn't compatible with your example input-- there's no `cat3`.  Puzzled me for a second.]

Comment: true, I'm editing @DSM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unstack('cat')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), followed by `fillna(0)` to replace the NaNs with zeros:

```
In [311]: test_df.groupby(['email','cat'])['class_price'].max().unstack('cat').fillna(0)
Out[311]: 
cat               cat1  cat2  cat3
email                             
email1@gmail.com     2     4     0
email2@gmail.com     0     2     1
email3@gmail.com     3     4     0
```

---

[`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) moves column level values to index level values.

[`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) moves index levels values to column level values. So when you see you have a `cat` index level and you want `cat` values in a column level, you can quickly recognize what's needed is an unstacking operation.